# Override app/code html file in app/design in magento 2

Tags: magento2

How do I override a html file that lives in `app/code/Mageplaza/Osc/view/frontend/web/template/1column.html`, and store the changes in my theme directory `app/design/frontend/ABC/Theme/...`?

I tried putting the changed file in 
`app/design/frontend/ABC/Theme/Osc/web/template/1column.html` and redeployed, which doesn't work.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you try   app/design/frontend/ABC/Theme/Mageplaza/Osc/web/template/1column.html ?
If your theme is called ABC/Theme that is. The override within the theme should have the same name for the directories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was close, looking at the `registration.php` file, they declared the name to be `Mageplaza_Osc`, so setting the file to be `app/design/frontend/ABC/Theme/Mageplaza_Osc/web/template/1column.html` fixes the problem.